# How to sum a numpy along the row axis by including only certain values per row according to variable length indices?

Tags: python, numpy

For the following array:

```py
array = [
  [1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 3],
  [3, 2, 4, 9, 11, 7],
  [8, 0, 9, 6, 23, 4]
]
```

How could we sum the elements (per row) as indicated by these indices:

```
indices = [
  [2, 4, 5],
  [1, 3],
  [4]
]
```

that is to say that:

- for the first row only the values on **indices** `[2, 4, 5]` will be considered when summing up -> `(6 + 10 + 3)`
- for the second row only the values on **indices** `[1, 3]` will be considered when summing up -> `(2 + 9)`
- and so on

Output:

```py
array([19, 11, 23])
```

The output has the same shape as if we did `array.sum(axis=1)` but not every value is included. Instead, the participants of each row are determined by the indices array.

I have thought of creating a mask for that purpose, but I did not know how to pass the indices to it.

Comment: How about a new array with 0 for the values you don't want to sum?

Comment: @hpaulj Could you please illustrate this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = np.array(array)
out = np.array([arr[idx, ind].sum() for idx, ind in enumerate(indices)])
out
```

Output : `array([19, 11, 23])`